# django ajax post 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, http-post, http-status-code-403

using django 1.4 im getting a 403 error when i try to do a post from my javascript do my django server. my get works fine though the problem is only with the post. also tried @csrf_exempt with no luck

UPDATE: I can Post now that i added `{% csrf_token %}` , but the post response comes empty, although the GET comes correctly, any ideas?

my django view:

```
@csrf_protect
def edit_city(request,username):
    conditions = dict()

    #if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        conditions = request.method

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print "TIPO" , request.GET.get('type','')       
        #based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/3634778/977622     
        for filter_key, form_key in (('type',  'type'), ('city', 'city'), ('pois', 'pois'), ('poisdelete', 'poisdelete'), ('kmz', 'kmz'), ('kmzdelete', 'kmzdelete'), ('limits', 'limits'), ('limitsdelete', 'limitsdelete'), ('area_name', 'area_name'), ('action', 'action')):
            value = request.GET.get(form_key, None)
            if value:
                conditions[filter_key] = value
                print filter_key , conditions[filter_key]

        #Test.objects.filter(**conditions)
    city_json = json.dumps(conditions)

    return HttpResponse(city_json, mimetype='application/json')
```

here is my javascript code :

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",
                             $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
    }
}
});

$.post(url,{ type : type , city: cityStr, pois: poisStr, poisdelete: poisDeleteStr, kmz: kmzStr,kmzdelete : kmzDeleteStr,limits : limitsStr, area_nameStr : area_nameStr , limitsdelete : limitsDeleteStr},function(data,status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    console.log("newdata" + data.area_name)
                });
```

i have also tried from the site with no luck :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Did you set DEBUG = True? Go to Chrome Dev Tools -> Network and click on your failed request. What message do you get in the Preview or Response tab?

Comment: i get a "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

Comment: strangely now my post response comes EMPTY, any idea why? the get still works fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30210391/940098

Answer (score 4, accepted):

got it working by adding `{% csrf_token %}` somewhere within the form in my template

Comment: csrf_token is an anti cross-site-request-forgery (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token, and is required because 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' is defined in the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES section of your settings.py.

Answer (score 26):

you can actually pass this along with your data  **{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}' }** , it works all the time

Comment: The name of the token should be "csrfmiddlewaretoken", instead of "csrftoken".  (Django 1.4)

Answer (score 6):

In my case I have a template in which I don't want to have a `<form></form>` element. But I still want to make AJAX POST requests using jQuery.

I got 403 errors, due to CSRF cookie being null, even if I followed the django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/csrf/). The solution is in the same page, mentioning the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator.

My CSRF cookie did get set when I added this at the top of my `views.py`:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
@ensure_csrf_cookie
```

Also, please note that in this case you *do not need* the DOM element in your markup / template: `{% csrf_token %}`

Comment: Thanks! I had to use the following before my class definition as I was using class-based views: @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='update')