# django ajax Post not posting propely and returns empty message

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, post, httpresponse

using django 1.4, I am trying to Post and it seems like its not posting propely, i `request.GET.get('type',''`) but it prints empty string and the Post response comes (undefined) empty but GET works fine.

my django view:

```
@csrf_protect
def edit_city(request,username):
    conditions = dict()

    #if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        conditions = request.method
#based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/3634778/977622     
            for filter_key, form_key in (('type',  'type'), ('city', 'city'), ('pois', 'pois'), ('poisdelete', 'poisdelete'), ('kmz', 'kmz'), ('kmzdelete', 'kmzdelete'), ('limits', 'limits'), ('limitsdelete', 'limitsdelete'), ('area_name', 'area_name'), ('action', 'action')):
                value = request.GET.get(form_key, None)
                if value:
                    conditions[filter_key] = value
                    print filter_key , conditions[filter_key]

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print "TIPO" , request.GET.get('type','')       
        #based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/3634778/977622     
        for filter_key, form_key in (('type',  'type'), ('city', 'city'), ('pois', 'pois'), ('poisdelete', 'poisdelete'), ('kmz', 'kmz'), ('kmzdelete', 'kmzdelete'), ('limits', 'limits'), ('limitsdelete', 'limitsdelete'), ('area_name', 'area_name'), ('action', 'action')):
            value = request.GET.get(form_key, None)
            if value:
                conditions[filter_key] = value
                print filter_key , conditions[filter_key]

        #Test.objects.filter(**conditions)
    city_json = json.dumps(conditions)

    return HttpResponse(city_json, mimetype='application/json')
```

here is my javascript code :

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",
                             $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
    }
}
});

$.post(url,{ type : type , city: cityStr, pois: poisStr, poisdelete: poisDeleteStr, kmz: kmzStr,kmzdelete : kmzDeleteStr,limits : limitsStr, area_nameStr : area_nameStr , limitsdelete : limitsDeleteStr},function(data,status){
                    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    console.log("newdata" + data.kmz)
                });
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, the problem was that i had to change this `request.GET.get('type','')` to this `request.POST.get('type','')`